# Interfaces in data oriented design

Tags: interface, abstraction, data-oriented-design

The saying goes something like this:

"Program to an interface/abstraction, not to an implementation".

We all know interfaces as a means of decoupling in object oriented programming. Like a contract that some object fulfills.

But something I cant wrap my head around is:

How do I program to an interface/abstraction in data oriented design?

Like in call some "Drawable" but I dont now if its a Rectangle or a Circle, but it implements the interface "Drawable".

Thanks

Comment: Can you perhaps detail your confusion a bit more? I’m not sure what you want to hear as an answer here.

Comment: Data itself is usless without methods. So no point to discuss this concepts this way. Or am I miss something ? plaese carify your question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a great question. I believe what you are asking is how do you achieve polymorphism with Data Oriented Design(DOD)?

**Short Answer:** You don't do it with interfaces. That's an Object Oriented Programming (OOP) way of achieving polymorphism. In DOD, polymophism can be achieved with the Entity Component System (ECS) pattern.

**Long Answer (with examples):**

Here is an example of polymorphism in OOP:

```
public interface Drawable
{
   void Draw();
}

public class Circle: Drawable
{
   public float posX, posY;
   public float radius;

   public void Draw() { /* Draw Circle */ }
}

public class Rectangle: Drawable
{
   public float posX, posY;
   public float width, height;

   public void Draw() { /* Draw Rectangle */ }
}
```

And here is how you achieve polymorphism with DOD and ECS (psuedo code):

```
public struct Position { public float x, y; }
public struct Circle { public float radius; }
public struct Rectangle { public float width, height; }

public class DrawCirlceSystem
{
    public void OnUpdate()
    {
        ComponentQuery
            .SelectReadOnly(typeof(Position), typeof(Circle))
            .ForEachEntity((Entity entity, Position position, Circle circle) => {
                /* Draw Circle */
            });
    }
}

public class DrawRectangleSystem
{
    public void OnUpdate()
    {
        ComponentQuery
            .SelectReadOnly(typeof(Position), typeof(Rectangle))
            .ForEachEntity((Entity entity, Position position, Rectangle rectangle) => {
                /* Draw Rectangle */
            });
    }
}
```

So if you had the following data layout:

```
Entity 1: [Position, Circle]
Entity 2: [Position, Circle]
Entity 3: [Position, Rectangle]
```

`DrawCircleSystem` will only execute over entities 1 and 2, while `DrawRectangleSystem` will only execute over entity 3. Thus, polymorphism is achieved through the queryability of these systems.

Programming in this way is much more performant then OOP. But beyond that, it also makes our code more scalable and optimizable. For example, if you wanted to implement culling so only the entities that are within view are actually rendered, we can easily do that with very little refactor effort. All we need to do is introduce a new system that handles the culling by adding or removing a new component called `Visible` to entities we want to draw:

```
public struct Visible { }

public class CircleCullingSystem
{
    public void OnUpdate()
    {
        // Give me all Circle entities that are NOT Visible
        ComponentQuery
            .SelectReadOnly(typeof(Position), typeof(Ciricle))
            .Exclude(typeof(Visible))
            .ForEachEntity((Entity entity, Position position, Circle circle) => { 
                // Add 'Visible' component to entity if it's within view range
            });

        // Give me all Circle entities that are Visible
        ComponentQuery
            .SelectReadOnly(typeof(Position), typeof(Ciricle))
            .FilterBy(typeof(Visible))
            .ForEachEntity((Entity entity, Position position, Circle circle) => { 
                // Remove 'Visible' component from entity if it's out of view range
            });

    }
}
```

And then we just update our query in the `DrawCirlceSystem` so that it filters by the `Visible` component:

```
public class DrawCirlceSystem
{
    public void OnUpdate()
    {
        // Process all visible circle entities
        ComponentQuery
            .SelectReadOnly(typeof(Position), typeof(Circle))
            .FilterBy(typeof(Visible))
            .ForEachEntity((Entity entity, Position position, Circle circle) => {
                /* Draw Circle */
            });
    }
}
```

And of course we would need to create a `RectangleCullingSystem` similar to our `CircleCullingSystem` since the culling behavior of rectangles is different from circles.

Comment: This is a great answer, sorry for the delay in getting back to you. It's not entirely clear to me however the data layout of the entities/components in the example. Are there arrays of components? Some say that the entity should only be a ID used as a key into arrays of components?

Comment: @krakers Sorry for the late reply as well on this. Yes, there are arrays of components. For the DrawCircleSystetm, it iterates over a position array (that holds the Position components of the entities 1 and 2) and the Circle array (that holds the Circle components of the entities 1 and 2). Using entity ID to get components you want is a thing, but for this common use case, the entity ID is not needed since both arrays line up with each other. So index 0 of those two arrays would be the Circle and Position components of entity 1.